# Iterating over an object of arrays and calculating average

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure and need to get an average value for each of the columns for the items in the contenders object. I then need to turn this into an array of arrays. The first value needs to be the columns average (rounded) the second needs to be an incremented value starting at 0. e.g.

```
output = [[6, 0], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [6, 4]];
```

Example structure:

```
input = {
  categories: [
    "Cat 1",
    "Cat 2",
    "Cat 3",
    "Cat 4",
    "Cat 5"
  ],
  contenders: {
    item1:       [5, 3, 4, 4, 6],
    item2:       [6, 10, 4, 4, 6],
    item3:       [6, 3, 4, 9, 6],
    item4:       [8, 3, 5, 4, 6],
    item5:       [9, 3, 4, 4, 6],
    item6:       [10, 2, 7, 4, 6],
    item7:       [4, 3, 4, 4, 6],
    item8:       [1, 5, 4, 4, 6]
  },
  misc: [0, 3, 4, 4, 6]
};
```

I've created a function that can do the average for me:

```
function getAvg(data) {
    return data.reduce(function (p, c) {
                return p + c;
            }) / data.length;
}
```

But can't quite work out how to iterate over the values for the items to get my result.

Comment: any reason why you have 8 contenders and only 5 elements in the output array? it is confusing

Comment: I undestand he wants an average of columns, not of each row (key). So all the answers kind of misunderstood

Comment: Its because the output array needs to match up with the categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`, for getting the properties and then interate over the values with `Array.prototype.forEach`.

```js
var input = { categories: ["Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3", "Cat 4", "Cat 5"], contenders: { item1: [5, 3, 4, 4, 6], item2: [6, 10, 4, 4, 6], item3: [6, 3, 4, 9, 6], item4: [8, 3, 5, 4, 6], item5: [9, 3, 4, 4, 6], item6: [10, 2, 7, 4, 6], item7: [4, 3, 4, 4, 6], item8: [1, 5, 4, 4, 6] }, misc: [0, 3, 4, 4, 6] },
    output = [],
    sum = [], count = [];

Object.keys(input.contenders).forEach(function (k) {
    input.contenders[k].forEach(function (a, i) {
        sum[i] = (sum[i] || 0) + a;
        count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
    });
});
output = sum.map(function (a, i) {
    return [Math.round(sum[i] / count[i]), i]
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: One other question if you don't mind. The content of the `misc` array is already averaged. I just need to get it to look like this: `output2 = [[9, 0], [9, 1], [9, 2], [9, 3],[4, 4]]` same format as `output`. What;s the best way to do this ?

Comment: @user1513388, `var output2 = input.misc.map(function (a, i) { return [a, i]; });` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly and you want an average of each column, which would mean each first element in all the arrays in your items keys as example, then you would need to make an array of each column to use your average function. However, in doing so you can already calculate the average, here is a way:

```js
      var input = { categories: ["Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3", "Cat 4", "Cat 5"], contenders: { item1: [5, 3, 4, 4, 6], item2: [6, 10, 4, 4, 6], item3: [6, 3, 4, 9, 6], item4: [8, 3, 5, 4, 6], item5: [9, 3, 4, 4, 6], item6: [10, 2, 7, 4, 6], item7: [4, 3, 4, 4, 6], item8: [1, 5, 4, 4, 6] }, misc: [0, 3, 4, 4, 6] }


    var output = []

    var cols = input.contenders.item1.length // amount of columns (I assume all items have same amount of columns)

    for(var i=0;i<cols;i++){
      output[i] = [0,i] // start output with sum of 0 and index i
    }

    for(var key in input.contenders){
      var arr = input.contenders[key]
      for(var k = 0;k<cols;k++){
        output[k][0]+=arr[k] // add the value of the array in the kth position to the kth output sum
      }
    }

    for(var i=0;i<cols;i++){
      output[i][0] = Math.round(output[i][0]/Object.keys(input.contenders).length) // now just divide by the amount of keys
    }

    console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get each item in the `contenders`, then use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array from the results:

```js
function getAvg(data) {
  return data.reduce(function (p, c) {
    return p + c;
  }) / data.length;
} 
var input = {
  categories: [
    "Cat 1",
    "Cat 2",
    "Cat 3",
    "Cat 4",
    "Cat 5"
  ],
  contenders: {
    item1:       [5, 3, 4, 4, 6],
    item2:       [6, 10, 4, 4, 6],
    item3:       [6, 3, 4, 9, 6],
    item4:       [8, 3, 5, 4, 6],
    item5:       [9, 3, 4, 4, 6],
    item6:       [10, 2, 7, 4, 6],
    item7:       [4, 3, 4, 4, 6],
    item8:       [1, 5, 4, 4, 6]
  },
  misc: [0, 3, 4, 4, 6]
};
console.log(Object.keys(input.contenders).map(function(key, index) {
  return [getAvg(input.contenders[key]), index];
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should totally go with `Object.keys` as suggested in other answers. However, for completeness or the unlikely case that compatibility gives you trouble:
You *can* build a string to refer to the arrays you're looking for, like so

```
for (var i=1;i<9;i++) { doSomething(input.contenders["item"+i]); }
```

This would require you to know the number of items and their names in advance.